# Why is this variable undefined within the object literal?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to store an object of selectors in jQuery for performance reasons and later use.

In some case, I may need to access a key in the same object literal I am creating.

```
(function($) {

    'use strict';

    var appCache = {

        $navSecondary: $('#nav-secondary'),
        $navMore: appCache.$navSecondary.find('.more')

    };

})(jQuery);
```

The above code produces the error:

```
TypeError: appCache is undefined
```

how can I get around this? Would I have to perform the selection again in jQuery?

Thanks.

Comment: When you call `appCache` to set `$navMore`, `appCache` is still `undefined`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right hand side of the assignment operator is evaluated first. The result is then passed left and assigned to the variable.

The variable is `undefined` while the object is being constructed, so you can't use its value (it has been declared though, `var` statements are hoisted).

You can assign a new property after the object has been created.

```
var appCache = {
    $navSecondary: $('#nav-secondary')
};
appCache["$navMore"] = appCache.$navSecondary.find('.more');
```

Comment: +1 for explaining why the above approach does not work and offering a solution at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var appCache = {

    $navSecondary: $('#nav-secondary'),
    $navMore: appCache.$navSecondary.find('.more')
              ^^^^^^^^

};
```

Because you are trying to access variable during its initialization.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function instead:

```
$navMore: function(){return this.$navSecondary.find('.more')}
```

Then call it once object is initialized:

```
appCache.$navMore(); // this will return set of jQuery matched elements
```